# Is there a clean portable way to "build" include-file names

Tags: c, macros, include, c-preprocessor, header-files

Many **C** projects have mile-long lists of "include" directories, and **C** source files often include tricky relative paths in their include directives. This can sometimes lead to ambiguities when files in different directories (and possibly serving different purposes) have the same name, and can also lead to slow compilation since the compiler has to search many places for each `#include` file.

A conceptually cleaner approach would be to have for each project a designated `#include` search directory which contained a `filepaths.h` file that would define macros for all the directories where include files resided, so that code anywhere in the project could then say something like

```
#include IO_INCLUDES(serialports.h)
#include IO_INCLUDES(timer.h)
#include FILESYS_INCLUDES(filesystem.h)
#include FILESYS_INCLUDES(dirhandling.h)
```

possibly with quotes; possibly without.  If **C** defined `#include "string1" "string2"` as equivalent to `#include "string1string2"`, handling include-files paths in such fashion would be easy, but it doesn't (in that case, the macros could accept arguments enclosed in quotes, and the macros could simply prepend suitable path names, also in quotes), but it doesn't.

An approach which almost works is to define things like:

```
... within a filepaths.h file
#define QUOTE(x) #x
#define MQUOTE(x) QUOTE(x)
#define DUP(x) x
#define MAKENAME(file,path) MQUOTE(DUP(file)DUP(path))

#define IO_INCLUDES(name) MAKENAME(d:/shared_libraries/io,name)
#define FILESYS_INCLUDES(name) MAKENAME(d:/shared_libraries/filesys,name)

... within an individual C file
#include IO_INCLUDES(serialport.h)
```

GCC seems to accept this, with proper desired semantics, *if no path name component is recognized specially by the preprocessor*.  Requiring that project files must be stored in paths whose names don't match any macros or anything else the preprocessor might recognize doesn't seem reasonable, however.

Is there any safe and portable way to allow a `filepaths.h` file to indicate the directories from which files should be retrieved?  The fact that the preprocessor accepts macros within `#include` directives would suggest that some such functionality was intended, but I can't figure out any way to make it work safely.  Is there one?

Comment: Have libraries. Sort out one or two include files for each library.  That will trim things

Comment: Rather than trying to set include paths with the preprocessor, one would normally set them in the make file or project settings...

Comment: @Dmitri: Unfortunately, doing that means that in a project where files get included from sixteen different directories, every `#include` directive will cause the compiler to look in all 16 directories.  Further, ambiguity and confusion may result if some `#include "../fnord.h"` statements find sometimes finds a `fnord.h` in the directory above the .C file being compiled but others use a `fnord.h` from a file in the directory above a directory in an include search path.

Comment: @Dmitri: While common practice seems to be to give the compiler a mile-long search path and hope for the best, that doesn't mean a more structured approach wouldn't be better.

Comment: @supercat I don't think what your trying to do will simplify things though.  Organizing your header files better and using the makefile/project settings will be much clearer.  Often there would be one or more main include paths with subdirectories to group the headers for different libraries/purposes, and the `#include` directives use relative paths within those.  As for the headers that are part of your project, you can organize them how you want and specify paths relative to your project directory.

Comment: @Dmitri: If all include file names are unique, and if `#include` directives refrain from specifying paths, then using makefile/project settings may be somewhat workable.  Trying to do make the compiler work sensibly with a vendor-supplied include file that contains something like `#include "../../../../syslib/uart/uart_typedefs.h"`, not so much.  If there is a good pattern, maybe vendors could start using it in place of the horrible relative paths (yes, I have seen some start with four `..`s) with something sensible.

Comment: having multiple header files with the same name is a sure sign that the system designer for the project did not do their job.  suggestion:  have only one or two places that contain .h files.  Then modify the .c files to only look in that one or two places.  if the header files cannot be moved, then place links in that one (or two) places that link to the actual .h files.  Above all, modify the file names so there are NO duplicates.

Comment: @user3629249: What should one do if a project needs to make use of two libraries from different vendors which happen to use identically-named nested .h files?

Comment: @user3629249: While prefixing all library includes with library-specific prefixes might be a good convention, it doesn't seem terribly common.  If two libraries both include a file e.g. `libtypes.h` but expect different contents, reconciling them will require hacking the files that use one or the other.  If the author of `FooLib` could change the header so that defining `FOOLIB_PATH` would cause the compiler to look there for FooLib-related includes, such conflicts could be resolved without having to hack any vendor-supplied files.

Comment: @supercat That's the reason for putting different libraries' headers in subdirectories of the main include directory -- that way the subfolder name acts like a library-specific prefix.. eg. `#include<libfoo/libtypes.h>` and `#include<libbar/libtypes.h>`

Comment: @Dmitri: Different vendors have different expectations about how things will be laid out.  If some libraries from different vendors are both dependent upon a .h file from the main chip vendor, and one of them writes #include "../cmq/cmq.h"`, another `#include "cmq/cmq.h"`, and a third `#include "cmq.h"` how should one keep them straight?

Answer (score 0):

There is not. According to 6.10.2 paragraph 4 of C99,
"The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or a pair of " characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined", so any attempt to do this will be nonportable.

You essentially have two options.  If you really want to have no restrictions on directory names at all, then you'll need to use a separate program to do this part of the preprocessing.  Make itself would probably be sufficient; something like m4 would be overkill here.

The other option, and the one I recommend, is to just establish a basic naming convention.  Make all your macro names be ALL-CAPS and all your directory names be not in all caps.  Then include your own headers before any others so you don't need to worry about what other people named their macros, and the problem vanishes.